# Moderation feedback to the editor of a message?

Tags: feature-request

I've edited the reply of a colleague of mine, added more details to his answer.
However, some moderators decided to discard my edits.

Now I don't get a feedback about that? Shouldn't I get a notification about the rejection?

He on the other hand [received a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10308019) via his `inbox messages`.